# byte + byte = unknown result

Tags: c#

Good day SO! I was trying to add two byte variables and noticed weird result.

```
byte valueA = 255;
byte valueB = 1;
byte valueC = (byte)(valueA + valueB);

Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", valueA.ToString(), 
                                     valueB.ToString(), 
                                     valueC.ToString());
```

when i tried to run the program, It displays

```
255 + 1 = 0
```

What happened to the above code? Why doesn't the compiler throws an `OverflowException`? How can I possibly catch the exception? I'm a VB guy and slowly migrating to C# :) Sorry for the question.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't overflow.  It does discard bits during the cast, but you explicitly asked it to do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C# code is `unchecked` by default, so that overflows will silently wrap around rather than throwing an exception.

You can get an exception by wrapping your code in a `checked` block, at the cost of a slight performance hist.

Answer (score 9):

because by default, `C#` doesn't check for arithmetic operation overflows. try wrapping it with `checked` so it will throw exception.

try this:

```
byte valueA = 255;
byte valueB = 1;
byte valueC = (byte)(valueA + valueB);

Console.WriteLine("Without CHECKED: {0} + {1} = {2}", valueA.ToString(), 
                                                      valueB.ToString(), 
                                                      valueC.ToString());

try
{
    valueC = checked((byte)(valueA + valueB));
    Console.WriteLine("With CHECKED: {0} + {1} = {2}", valueA.ToString(), 
                                                       valueB.ToString(), 
                                                       valueC.ToString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("With CHECKED: " + e.GetType());
}
```

**[checked @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**